# typecasting an address in C

Tags: c, pointers, typecast-operator

Why there is a need to typecast an address when a pointer is pointing to an address?

**Example**

```
uint32_t *ptr = (uint32_t *) 0x40008000;
```

What will be the result if we don't typecast the address?

Comment: `0x40008000` is an *integer* (literal); the cast is to inform the compiler to use the integer *as an address*.

Comment: With gcc or clang, you should be compiling with the `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` options. Then the answer to this question becomes self evident.

Comment: If you don't cast it is a constraint violation, because the program is invalid. Unfortunately C compilers are allowed to compile invalid programs too, provided that they issue a doagnostic message (i.e. "a warning")